# How to Convert this date to mySQL time using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

20101109-240000
or
20101109-235959

How to convert the date format above into MySQL format, Y-m-d H:i:s

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$mysqldate = preg_replace('/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\-(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/', '$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6',$date)`

Comment: You used $i, I think you wanted to use $1 !

Answer (score 1):

Use STR_TO_DATE() MySQL function :

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20101109-235959', '%Y%m%d-%H%i%s');
-- 2010-11-09 23:59:59
```

P.S. 20101109-240000 wouldn't work because it is not a valid timestamp.